# Why go get downloads two versions of same package when using -u

Tags: go

I was using `go get -u` to get a package which depends on `golang.org/x/text@v0.3.7`. I noticed that it first downloads `golang.org/x/text@v0.3.7` then downloads `golang.org/x/text@v0.4.0`.

Then I ran `go clean -modcache` and `go get golang.org/x/text` which downloaded `v0.4.0` of `golang.org/x/text` and then again `go get -u entgo.io/ent`. This time go didn't download `golang.org/x/text@v0.3.7`

So, Why `go get -u` downloads both the old version and latest version when the latest version is not present locally, and Why it doesn't download the old version when the latest version is available locally?

Comment: -u means updata

Comment: @Para My question is what is the need for downloading old version before updating to latest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is a two-step process of

1. Getting dependencies
2. Updating dependencies

From a programming standpoint there is no good reason to merge these into a single concern of "Get latest dependencies".

From the [go command documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Add_dependencies_to_current_module_and_install_them):

> The -u flag instructs get to update modules providing dependencies of packages named on the command line to use newer minor or patch releases when available.

This means that `-u` specifically deals with modules which the package you are getting depends on, rather than with the module of the package you are getting.

Furthermore, it appears that `-u` is agnostic to the Go idiom of treating any change in a `v0` version as a major version change, so one cannot lightheartedly recommend using `-u` out of principle. The [README of golang.org/x/test](https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/text/+/master:README.md) even says:

> Until version 1.0.0 of x/text is reached, the minor version is considered a major version. So going from 0.1.0 to 0.2.0 is considered to be a major version bump.